# Skip series in batch download with wget in a bash script

Tags: bash, wget

How can i skip a folder in a bash script using wget to batch download files, if the last file checked does not exist?

Here is the sample code:

```
#!/bin/bash
# Script to download Reports @ brazil.crl.edu/bsd/bsd
# Url : start @ http://brazil.crl.edu/bsd/bsd/u2038/ ends: /u2176
# There are less than 1000 files per address.
base1='http://brazil.crl.edu/bsd/bsd/u'
for i in {2038..2176};do 
    for s in {000001..001000}; do
        wget -r $base1$i'/'$s'.tiff'
        if [ $? -eq 0 ]; then
            break
        fi
    done
done
```

It's downloading only the first file. Can someone help?

Comment: You are querying for an exit status of `0`, which stands for "no errors occurred". Seemingly all 1st files exist. Change this to `if [ $? -ne 0 ] ; then`, i.e. "any error occurred" and you should be fine. See `man wget` at the `EXIT STATUS` section. You could also use `bash`'s boolean logic as `wget -r $base1$i'/'$s'.tiff' || break` which will execute break on a bad `wget` termination.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In order to enable you to mark this question as "solved", here the answer from my comment:

Your query

```
if [ $? -eq 0 ]
```

is checking for an exit status of `0`, which stands for "No problems occurred" (according to `man wget`, EXIT STATUS section). Thus reversing the if-query to

```
if [ $? -ne 0 ]
```

i.e. "any problem occurred" will resolve the problem.

An exit status of `0` is the standard for successful execution of a command.

The if query could be reduced using `bash`'s operator `||` which will check for unsuccessful command termination:

```
wget -r $base1$i'/'$s'.tiff' || break
```